# How to show that both $D^{+,b}(\mathcal{A})$ and $D^{-,b}(\mathcal{A})$ are equivalent to $D^b(\mathcal{A})$?

Tags: triangulated-categories, derived-categories

Let $\mathcal{A}$ be an abelian category. $K(\mathcal{A}), K^{+}(\mathcal{A}),K^{-}(\mathcal{A}),K^{b}(\mathcal{A})$ are triangulated categories of homotopy complexes of unbounded, bounded below, bounded above, bounded, respctively. $K^{+,b}(\mathcal{A})$(resp.$K^{-,b}(\mathcal{A})$) is the full triangulated subcategory of  $K^{+}(\mathcal{A})$(resp.$K^{-}(\mathcal{A})$) having bounded cohomology.

Associated to a choice $K^{*}(\mathcal{A})$ of one of above is the derived category $D^{*}(\mathcal{A})$, that is the localization of $K^{*}(\mathcal{A})$ with respect to the quasi-isomorphisms.

How to show that both $D^{+,b}(\mathcal{A})$ and $D^{-,b}(\mathcal{A})$ are equivalent to $D^b(\mathcal{A})$?

Comment: Basic idea is this: take a bounded cochain complex $C$. Take a Cartan-Eilenberg resolution of injectives for $C$ (bounded below gives existence). The map from $C$ to the total complex of the resolution will be a quasi-isomorphism. So for any object in $\mathcal{D}^b$ we associate it with an object of $\mathcal{K}^{-,b}(I)$; complexes of injectives with bounded cohomology. This should be a localizing subcat of $K^{-,b}$, so we just localize it to get the derived category. But quasi-isomorphisms in this category will be isomorphisms.

Comment: @BigMathTimes Yes, I know that $D^b(\mathcal{A}) \cong K^{-,b}(I)$. Do you mean all quai-isomorphisms in $K^{-,b}(I)$ are isomrophisms? Then I can get $D^b(\mathcal{A}) \cong D^{-,b}(I)$. So how to get $D^{-,b}(I) \cong D^{-,b}(\mathcal{A})$?

Comment: All quasi-isos there are isos, yes. I was working with injectives because I worry about universes, sorry I think I have a better answer without them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a complex bounded below $(C^{*}, \delta)$ that is eventually exact. Say $0 = H^{n+1} = H^{n+12}=...$. We want to find a bounded complex that is quasi-isomorphic to $(C^*,\delta)$. To do this, take $(D^{i}, \delta)$ to be the complex with $D^{i} = C^{i}$ for $i \leq n$, and the same coboundary map. But let $D^{n+1} = \text{coker }\delta$, and each $D^{*}$ onward to be $0$. Take the map from $D^*$ to $C^*$ which is the identity on each $C^{i}$, and the natural map $D^{n+1}$ to $C^{n+1}$ coming from the cokernel property (since $\delta^2 = 0$). This map is a chain map - commutativity at the last step is just the cokernel property. It is a quasi-isomorphism, since it is the identity on the part with non-zero homology.

So to each object in $D^{-,b}$, we get an isomorphic object in $D^{b}$. Using a kernel, we can do similarly for $D^{+,b}.$ This should show the equivalence.